# Help with script / IFS / for fn in $(cat list.txt)

Tags: bash

I have a list of files in the format

```
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
newline
newline
file4.jpg
file5.jpg
file6.jpg
newline
newline
file7.jpg
file8.jpg
file9.jpg
etc
```

my bash script sets to IFS=$"\n"
I want to skip the first file, delete the remaining files, and then when the two newlines come along, reset count to 0 and do it again for the next batch.  When I set IFS to a single newline, I get unexpected results -- the image files no longer parse properly.  When you delete IFS from the script, the script does not detect the two newlines.  Help! And thanks in advance.

the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# MASS DELETE
#
IFS=$"\n\n"
count=0
deleted=0
saved=0
for fn in $(cat list.txt)
do
        length=${#fn}
        ext=${fn:length-3:3}
        echo "**$fn**"

        if [ $ext != "jpg" ]; then
                echo "**Newline**"
                count=0
        else
#               (( ++count ))
#               if [ $count -ge 1 ]; then
#                       echo "Removing $fn..."
#                       #rm $fn
#               else
#                       echo "Saving $fn..."
#               fi
                echo "Do Stuff"
        fi
done
```

Output (wrong!)

```
Rigel@Minty-VirtualBox:~/data/comics/2020$ ./mass_del.sh
**12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-10.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-11.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-30.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-17.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-21.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-28.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-01.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-03.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-12.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-15.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-20.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-25.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-07.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-27.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-29.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-16.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-26.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-02.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-18.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-06.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-19.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-13.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-04.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-31.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-22.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-24.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-14.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-05.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-09.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-08.jpg
12-Dec/miltpriggee-2020-12-23.jpg


12-Dec/kevi**
**Newline**
```

Comment: In this script IFS is set to "\n\n" which has the same output as $"\n".

Comment: You've talked about "_two newlines_", but in the example it looks like it's actually a sequence of three newlines (one to end a line of data, and then two explicit newlines). Which is it?

Comment: Probably 3 then ... data/n/n/n before restart of a new block.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in `awk` provided that the file names do not contain a single quote:

```
awk -v q="'" '
    $0 == "" { count=0; next }
    count++ { print "Delete:", $0; system("echo rm -f -- " q $0 q) }
' list.txt
```

If you really want to use a shell loop you can do it like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    # Blank line resets the skip counter
    if [ -z "$line" ]
    then
        count=0

    # Skip the first non-blank line (count==0) then delete others
    elif [ $((count++)) -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo "Delete: $line"
        echo rm -f -- "$line"
    fi
done <list.txt
```

In both cases remove the leading `echo` from `echo rm` to action the file deletion.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

bash, and shell scripting in general, is a poor tool for this job.  You'd be better off doing this in awk or perl or something.  For example:

```
perl -00 -F'\n' -ae 'shift @F; push @del, @F; END {unlink @del}' list.txt
```

`-00` tells perl to read its input, `list.txt`, in paragraph mode (paragraphs are separated by one or more blank lines).  The `-a` option causes perl to auto-split each input paragraph into an array called `@F` (using newlines as the delimiter due to the `-F'\n'` option). The script then discards the first element of @F (with `shift`), and adds the remainder of @F to another array called `@del` with `push`.   When all the input has been read and processed, the `END` block is executed, which deletes (unlinks) all filenames in the `@del` array.

It would be easy to add a confirmation question to this if you wanted - e.g. "Delete nnn files (yes/NO)?", perhaps listing all the files to be deleted, before deleting them.  Or just print a count of files that were deleted.

If you wanted to do the deletions in bash for some reason, you could have it print the `@del` array (using NUL as the separator between filenames) in the END block instead of `unlink @del`, and a bash script could pipe the output into something like `xargs -0r rm`.  e.g.

```
perl -00 -F'\n' -ae '
    shift @F; push @del, @F;
    END { print join("\0", @del), "\0" }' list.txt |
  xargs -0r rm
```

---

Here's another, shorter, version that unlinks the files after each paragraph is read, rather than all in one go at the end.  This version doesn't bother to keep a cumulative list of files to be deleted:

```
perl -00 -F'\n' -ae 'shift @F; unlink @F' list.txt
```

---

To show how these scripts work, here's a slightly different version that doesn't delete anything. Instead it just prints what it would do.

```
$ perl -00 -F'\n' -ae '
  push @keep, shift @F;
  push @del, @F;
  END {
    printf "Keep   %i: %s\n", scalar @keep, join(", ", @keep);
    printf "Delete %i: %s\n", scalar @del, join(", ", @del)
  }' list.txt 
Keep   3: file1.jpg, file4.jpg, file7.jpg
Delete 6: file2.jpg, file3.jpg, file5.jpg, file6.jpg, file8.jpg, file9.jpg
```

Instead of just discarding the first element of @F, it adds it to an array called `@keep`.  The remaining elements are added to `@del`, as before.  The END block prints both arrays, with a count of the files that would be kept or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `IFS=$"\n\n"` is the same as setting `IFS='\n\n'`, it sets it to backslash, letter n, backslash, letter n. To get the backslash-escapes interpreted, you need to use `$'...'`, not `$"..."`, the latter is for internationalization (iirc).

Anyway, it doesn't help you here, since word splitting treats consecutive whitespace separators as one, so `foo<newline><newline>bar` splits into `foo` and `bar`, the same as `foo<newline>bar`. (This isn't the case for non-whitespace separators, e.g. `foo::bar` with `IFS=:` does retain the empty field, but that doesn't help you here either.)

It's probably easier to just read the file line-by-line. This would treat even a single empty line as separator, since that's far easier and I fail to see what you'd otherwise do with the empty lines:

```
first=1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # skip leading empty lines and the first non-empty one
    if [ "$first" ]; then
        if ! [ -z "$line" ]; then
            echo "skipping $line"
            first=
        fi
        continue
    fi
    # if line is not empty, remove the file
    # if empty, go back to first line processing
    if [ "$line" ]; then
        echo rm -- "$line"
    else
        first=1
    fi
done
```

With input like

```
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg


file4.jpg
file5.jpg
file6.jpg

file7.jpg
file8.jpg
file9.jpg
```

that would give

```
skipping file1.jpg
rm -- file2.jpg
rm -- file3.jpg
skipping file4.jpg
rm -- file5.jpg
rm -- file6.jpg
skipping file7.jpg
rm -- file8.jpg
rm -- file9.jpg
```

The `echo` before the `rm` is the safety catch, remove it to actually delete the files.

---

Of course, you could do the same in Perl, which could remove the files without forking off `rm` for each and every one, and so would be faster. Nicking the logic from @roaima's answer:

```
$ perl -lne 'chomp; if (/^$/) { $count=0; next; }; 
             next if ($count++ == 0); 
             print "delete: $_"; 
             next; 
             unlink($_) or warn "unlink ($_): $!"' < foo.txt
delete: file2.jpg
delete: file3.jpg
delete: file5.jpg
delete: file6.jpg
delete: file8.jpg
delete: file9.jpg
```

The `next` between the `print` and `unlink` is the safety catch, remove it to actually delete the files.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` + GNU `xargs`:

```
$ awk 'NF&&p;{p=NF}' list.txt | xargs -rd'\n' echo rm --
rm -- file2.jpg file3.jpg file5.jpg file6.jpg file8.jpg file9.jpg etc
```

Remove `echo` if output is correct.